# Audio stream to file with ffmpeg but trim the audio after a specific time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

Is there a way to save an audio stream to a file with ffmpeg but trim it automatically after it reaches a certain time?

I'm saving a stream from fmstream.org to a raw file then I stream it from there somewhere else. Now the problem I'm facing is that the file is becoming too big with the time and I'm looking to get rid of the unneeded audio to keep the file size as small as possible.

Currently I'm running ffmpeg with:

`ffmpeg -i https://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_radio_one -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 ar 48k -y radio.raw`

Comment: This feels like a bit of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Why do you need to save it to re-transmit? This also seems like a task better suited to VLC.

Comment: I'm sharing the audio to a telegram group call and the library I'm using needs the file to be stored on my server and in a .raw format

Comment: Can you not pipe the audio to the library?

Comment: Nah. I don't think I actually can. I'll have to take a look at the source code and see if I there's a way of doing that. Since it's in python probably I'll have to find some kind of library too idk. Anyway one way I could do this is to prepare another stream file after a few seconds has passed and a while after that to pass the new file to the library

Comment: Nvm. I can send data in bytes to the library to play my stream. Dope